# Has a pilot ever accidentally skipped an item in the before takeoff checklists and survived?

Tags: accidents, aircraft-operations, checklist

I would like to know if there are any documented events where a pilot has accidentally skipped an item from a before takeoff checklist, but managed to avoid an incident, reaching their destination safely.

Comment: What kind of documentation will you accept, and must it be accidental or could it also be on purpose?

Comment: Happens all the time.  There are only a few items where skipping an item will kill you.  Leaving control locks on, taking off with fuel selected off and the the engine runs until the carb bowl is empty.  Most of the items, it's just an ooopsie. On jets. add some more critical items, like leaving the anti-ice off taking off in icing conditions, wrong takeoff flap setting etc. Even on jets, most of the checklist items are just oopsies if you forget them.  Jets have Takeoff Configuration Warning Systems for the safety critical items if you miss that checklist item.

Comment: I was doing a checkride with a new CFI.  We were going to use my plane.  The battery was flat so I went to hunt down a new one from my CAMO.  In the meantime the CFI checked my insurance and realised he wouldn't be covered as P1.  So we decided to take his plane (same model).  By now time was pressing, Rushed through my walkaround and prestart checks, taxi-ed to the hold and did the power checks, took off and stooged around. On downwind, during BUMPFITCHH I realised I'd flown the whole hour without fastening my harness.  I guess this isn't the sort of thing you're looking for?

Comment: @JohnK: you can add forgetting to set the cabin pressurization switch to "auto": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helios_Airways_Flight_522

Comment: @JohnK For Air Carrier operations anyway I disagree that it *happens all of the time*. "Read and Do" and "Challenge and Response" checklists require both pilots to interact and fail if an item is missed. Missing an item is a serious breach of professionalism and a complete failure of the standards of operation that professional pilots are trained and checked on (definitely not an "ooopsie"). In my experience with Air Carrier ops it was rare, although it has happened, that an item was missed. Skipping an item on purpose is inexcusable.

Comment: @757toga yes agreed.  I dunno about others, but on the CRJ there was a big weak link; you select WAI on not until while pulling out onto the runway (LEs get steam iron hot), and it's an action you do after stowing the TO checklist during the lineup. Easy to forget. I'm surprised there weren't more crashes from forgetting.  Later they add a subsystem that cycles low heat to the LEs while taxiing automatically as a safety measure.

Comment: @Jim Doesn't need to be anything too formal. Even something like an interview with a pilot saying that they'd forgotten a checklist item would do.

Comment: Consider me interviewed then, because I have probably done it a few times and here I am...  You really only hear about these sort of mistakes when something bad happens.  (not sure the "agenda" of your question, but it's a bit like trying to prove a negative)

Comment: Forgetting flaps is fun. Two big clues is 1) lifts off later than expected after rotation. 2) begins to climb, just,  and then "mushes" as it is getting out of ground effect.  These are not mentioned in the tech manual but I'm aware of them.  Living or dying can be a matter of not having to maneuver immediately,  lots of runway in front of you, thus having enough time to trigger that subconscious brain-to-hand-to-flap-lever neural pathway.

Comment: I'm in this post and I don't like it :)

Comment: Skipping checklist items is, unfortunately, something that happens thousands of times a day. Since there aren’t thousands of fatal accidents per day, what more proof are you looking for?

Comment: Prior to around WWII, checklists didn't even exist.  They came about because in pursuit of performance, Boeing had created (in the B-17) a more complex aircraft than predecessors, and the prototype crashed because something was forgotten.

Comment: *... it happens all of the time*  =>  No, as @757toga says. BUT there are so many flights worldwide every day that *something* happens all the time. Each unique chain of events typically determines the consequences of every "something."

Answer (score 8):

Yes, I forgot to preflight the pitot tube, took off, had no accurate airspeed indication, the airspeed indicator acted as a cross between an altimeter and a rate of climb indicator.  The pitot side of the system seemed to be basically sealed up tight, but with a very slow leak to the outside atmosphere.  Ascending to approx 8000', the ASI initially showed a very high value, but very slowly leaked down toward zero, and then when I descended back to the ground two hours later, the ASI showed a negative value.  (Needle was left, or counter-clockwise, of zero.)  I refrained from taking any unusual actions to deal with the apparent negative airspeed.
After landing I noticed the pitot tube was plugged up tight with dried dirt, undoubtedly due to the action of a mud-dauber wasp.  Documentation exists in the form of digital photos saved to my hard drive-- both from mid-flight and after landing.

The event happened more than 24 hours ago, so I hope that counts as "in history".

Comment: If you're properly trained and skilled as I'm sure you are, loss of airspeed should be a total non-event, as I'm sure it was.

Comment: :-) Loss of airspeed indication might be a non-event, but loss of airspeed is another matter.

Comment: “Airspeed not alive… not 60 knots… rotate...”

Comment: As a precaution, I would have jettisoned the canopy to facilitate bailing out, except that the aircraft had an open cockpit. : ;  (Joke, but the last part is true, and I was wearing a parachute! )

Comment: Oops I guess this deals with preflight while the actual question was about pre-takeoff checklist- oh well--